# Can OpenApi Generator generate interface feign clients?

Tags: java, gradle, openapi, openapi-generator, openfeign

Is it possible to generate feign clients using OpenApiGenerator?

This is my current setup:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.11'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
    id "org.openapi.generator" version "6.3.0"
}

group = 'dev.rifaii'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:4.0.2'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

def swaggerCodeGenConfig = {
    generatorName = "spring"
    remoteInputSpec = "someUrl"
    outputDir = "$projectDir/external/src/main/java"
    apiPackage = 'somepackageForApis'
    modelPackage = 'somepackageForModels'
    additionalProperties = [
            packageName: "petstore",
            interfaceOnly: 'true',
            feign      : 'true'
    ]
}


task buildExampleClient(type: org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask) {
    configure swaggerCodeGenConfig
    remoteInputSpec = "http://158.101.191.70:8081/v3/api-docs"
    apiPackage = 'dev.rifaii.example.api'
    modelPackage = 'dev.rifaii.example.model'
}
```

what this task is currently generating:

```java
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2023-05-09T00:05:09.505990300+03:00[Europe/Tallinn]")
@Validated
@Tag(name = "store", description = "the store API")
public interface StoreApi {

    default Optional<NativeWebRequest> getRequest() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    /**
     * DELETE /store/order/{orderId} : Delete purchase order by ID
     * For valid response try integer IDs with value &lt; 1000. Anything above 1000 or nonintegers will generate API errors
     *
     * @param orderId ID of the order that needs to be deleted (required)
     * @return Invalid ID supplied (status code 400)
     *         or Order not found (status code 404)
     */
    @Operation(
        operationId = "deleteOrder",
        summary = "Delete purchase order by ID",
        description = "For valid response try integer IDs with value < 1000. Anything above 1000 or nonintegers will generate API errors",
        tags = { "store" },
        responses = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Invalid ID supplied", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "*/*", schema = @Schema(implementation = Map.class))
            }),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Order not found")
        }
    )
    @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.DELETE,
        value = "/store/order/{orderId}",
        produces = { "*/*" }
    )
    default ResponseEntity<Void> deleteOrder(
        @Parameter(name = "orderId", description = "ID of the order that needs to be deleted", required = true, in = ParameterIn.PATH) @PathVariable("orderId") Long orderId
    ) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

    }
   }
```

All I want is for it to generate interfaces that look like this

```java
@FeignClient("someClient")
public interface SomeClient {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/example")
    List<SomeObject> getExample();
}
```

In another project I used an old version of swagger codegen with Springfox and I was able to achieve this but I'm not sure how to do it with openapi generator

Comment: Sometimes, I wonder why answers are neither accepted nor upvoted...

Answer (score 1):

`@RequestMapping` in the Feign client has long been discouraged and bad practice. It lead to [CVE-2021-22044](https://spring.io/security/cve-2021-22044) and the functionality to support `@RequestMapping` was removed altogether in Feign clients due to the aforementioned security issue.

Having said that, based on the documentation for the `spring` generator: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/spring.md

Specifying the `library` configuration as `spring-cloud` should yield what you want.

Comment: I'm so very confused, since the front page example uses it. What are they encouraging? https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-openfeign

Comment: @xenoterracide The examples show _method_ level which is fine. It is _class_ level that was the issue.

Comment: Im confused, maybe the OP edited it, but I don't see any class level annotations, so why the reprimand

Comment: @Cisco, according to documentation link of generator, that you suggest, has generator type SERVER, i.e. it's purpose to generate implementation by openapi specification, not client. Closest of available client generators is 'feign'